# MATLAB - Generating a rand value vector (each value [0; 1] with at least X% zeros)?

Tags: matlab

Does anybody know an efficent way to retrieve such a result?

I could of course use rand(n,1) and then replace by iterating over the array values with zeros until the number of zeros is sufficient. (as written above atleast X% zeros it can also be more but not less)

I would prefer a completly random distribution but also a uniform distribution would be fine. (So I have no real clue how the distribution effects the result)

(Currently using MATLAB 2017a)

Comment: The answer depends on which distribution you want for the resulting vector. For example, uniformly distributed on the subset of vectors with X% or more zeros? Or uniform distribution for the number of zeros (conditioned on being at least X%)? Would a rejection approach be acceptable for you (random running time)?

Comment: “I would prefer a completly random distribution but also a uniform distribution would be fine.” This makes little sense. Completely random is not a distribution. Are you talking about a normal distribution, a binomial distribution, a Poisson distribution,...?

Comment: I tried to say that the generated values can be ordered/distributed completely random. Could you explain more precisely why a distribution of values can not be random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `A=rand(n);` to generate random vector, then use `num = randi([n*proc,n]);` to figure out how many of the numbers should be changed for 0 (`proc` is the minimum fraction of numbers which should be 0). Substitute for 0 with `A(1:num)=0;` and then shuffle the array with `B = A(randperm(n));`.

In total:

```
A=rand(n);
proc = 0.3;
num = randi([n*proc,n]);
A(1:num)=0;
B = A(randperm(n));
```